# Is generating URLs for temporary access to a private resource safe?

Tags: authentication, url, https, privacy

I am making a small website for a shop, it is nearly a landing page. There is no account system for customers. The website has a page to view order details, the page is only meant to be viewed by the person who made the order. So I need a way to authenticate requests to that page.

I decided to apply this system for authorizing access to order information:

- When a customer posts an order they specify their email. So I can use the email to authenticate requests that access the order details.
- When a customer wants to access order details they enter their order ID in a special form on the landing page. Then they'll receive a URL with a newly generated key in its path in an email message. The URL leads to the details page for the requested order. The following rules are applied to this URL for security:

  1. The URL will be valid only for about 6 hours.
  2. The first client that uses the URL gets the URL associated with its cookie-based session. Later only the client with that session cookie is allowed to view the page.
  3. All such URLs, even expired ones, have a unique key.

Is this idea safe? Is putting the key in URL path safe? I'll be using a cryptographically secure random number generator to generate the keys, what can I do to quickly generate unique keys without repeatedly generating keys and checking each one against DB until I find an unoccupied one?

Comment: One trick would be to invalidate the link after it's been accessed once.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a GUID which is a good way to make sure it is unique (it's 128 bits long, so generating duplicates is extremely unlikely. 2<sup>128</sup> is a really big number). I'm not sure what server-side language you're using but you should be able to use an existing library to generate these Guids.

Alternatively, you could generate random 16-character alphanumeric IDs. With 36 possible characters ([a-z] and [0-9]), the number of possible combinations is 36<sup>16</sup> (around 10<sup>25</sup> or 2<sup>83</sup>), which tells you there is a really low chance of collisions for this use case. The nice thing about this option is that the IDs you generate will be a lot shorter and not look so bad in a URL.

I would avoid putting these identifiers in the URL path just in case your site could be crawled or exploited in some way to leak a listing of these paths.  But I would think it would be okay to pass the identifiers in the URL's query string. Just make sure the identifiers aren't leaked elsewhere.
I would also recommend minimizing the amount of sensitive information you can view on the order page, such as payment details.